# Restrict image upload size in sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1, sitecore-media-library

Is there a way to control image upload size in Sitecore?

is it possible to have a custom warning message on uploading a large file?

We are on Sitecore 8.1 update 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use setting:

```xml
<setting name="Media.MaxSizeInDatabase" value="500MB"/>
```

Comment: is it possible to have a custom warning message on uploading a large file?

Comment: Negative. The `CheckSize` processor has a hard coded message.